# Что сделать чтобы работал поиск по тегам в Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint

Не работает поиск по тегам. Пишет: Нет результатов, соответствующих вашим условиям поиска.

В журнале обхода контента после обхода контента возникает ошибка:
`http://mysite.domain.local:8080/tagprofile.aspx`
`Sharepoint` вернул пустой ответ. `( SearchID = 8A03661D-5787-4EC3-B49F-640DB6B3C2B1 )`

В логе по ID нашел следующие записи:

```
04.22.2016 13:18:22.37  mssdmn.exe (0x1754)  0x0108  SharePoint Server Search           Connectors:HTTP            du4s                Medium              CHttpAccessorHelper::InitRequestInternal - Request/Response succeeded CorrelationID b5ec749d-26a9-8025-14bf-6bc473284c51 URL сайт/tagprofile.aspx SearchRequestTime 656, SPRequestDuration 0, SPIISLatency 663, dwStatusCode 200, hr 0x0  [httpacchelper.cxx:586]  search\native\gather\protocols\http\httpacchelper.cxx            8a03661d-5787-4ec3-b49f-640db6b3c2b1
04.22.2016 13:18:22.37  mssdmn.exe (0x1754)  0x0108  SharePoint Server Search           Connectors:SharePoint                ail45       High       CSTS3Accessor::Init: SharePoint returned an empty response for URL сайт/tagprofile.aspx CrawlTarget  CorrelationID b5ec749d-26a9-8025-14bf-6bc473284c51, hr=8004FD3A  [sts3acc.cxx:652]  search\native\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3acc.cxx         8a03661d-5787-4ec3-b49f-640db6b3c2b1
04.22.2016 13:18:22.37  mssdmn.exe (0x1754)  0x0108  SharePoint Server Search           Connectors:SharePoint                dv44      High       CSTS3Accessor::Init: InitRequest failed for URL сайт/tagprofile.aspx Return error to caller, hr=8004FD3A  [sts3acc.cxx:666]  search\native\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3acc.cxx           8a03661d-5787-4ec3-b49f-640db6b3c2b1
04.22.2016 13:18:22.37  mssdmn.exe (0x1754)  0x0108  SharePoint Server Search           Connectors:SharePoint                dvb1      Medium              CSTS3Accessor::Init fails, Url sts4://mysite.domain.local:8080/siteurl=/siteid={727643c2-c4f0-4abf-b754-664dccb5c950}/weburl=/webid={11c83363-1f80-48e5-9b19-b9ed366425bf}/fpfolder=/fpitemid=tagprofile.aspx, hr=8004FD3A  [sts3handler.cxx:337]  search\native\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3handler.cxx      8a03661d-5787-4ec3-b49f-640db6b3c2b1
04.22.2016 13:18:22.37  mssdmn.exe (0x1754)  0x0108  SharePoint Server Search           Connectors:SharePoint                dvb2      Medium              CSTS3Handler::CreateAccessorExD: Return error to caller, hr=8004FD3A            [sts3handler.cxx:355]  search\native\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3handler.cxx   8a03661d-5787-4ec3-b49f-640db6b3c2b1
```

При нажатии на ссылку `http://mysite.domain.local:8080/tagprofile.aspx` открывается пустая страница (может так и должно быть?).
Если открыть эту ссылку с параметром id тега, например, сайт `/tagprofile.aspx?termid=1a41ded1-af94-4575-9d21-105afa372885`, то открывается профиль тега.

Хотя, обычный поиск по словам, встречающимся где-либо, работает. 
Не могу понять где уже что надо сделать, чтобы заработало. Службы (профилей пользователей, синхронизации профилей, управляемых метаданных, поиска) работают. Права на службы и на Web приложения даны. Теги, которые добавляются к каким-нибудь сущностям (например, к записи блога, документу библиотеки) появляются  на странице управления банками терминов. Делал сброс индекса, очистку кэша. И службу поиска переставлял.

Еще заметил, что в самом профиле тега в разделе 'Элементы с тегами' ничего нет. Правильно ли я понимаю, что если где-либо помечен какой-нибудь элемент этим тегом, то информация об этом элементе должна быть отражена в профиле тега?
`Sharepoint версии 2013 SP1`
Может кто даст какой совет, направление в каком направлении, так сказать, копать.
С Уважением, Евгений.